# How to make class instance constructable in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert this package to TypeScript without any breaking changes. I have the following code in TypeScript.

```js
// DocumentCarrier.ts
/* export */ class DocumentCarrier {
    internalObject: {};
    model: Model;
    save: (this: DocumentCarrier) => void;

    constructor(model: Model, object: {}) {
        this.internalObject = object;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
DocumentCarrier.prototype.save = function(this: DocumentCarrier): void {
    console.log(`Saved document ${JSON.stringify(this.model)} to ${this.model.myName}`);
};

// Model.ts
// import {DocumentCarrier} from "./DocumentCarrier.ts";
/* export */class Model {
    myName: string;
    Document: typeof DocumentCarrier;
    get: (id: number) => void;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.myName = name;

        const self: Model = this;
        class Document extends DocumentCarrier {
            static Model: Model;

            constructor(object: {}) {
                super(self, object);
            }
        }
        Document.Model = self;

        Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).forEach((key) => {
            Document[key] = this[key].bind(this);
        });

        this.Document = Document;

        return this.Document as any;
    }
}
Model.prototype.get = function(id: number): void {
    console.log(`Retrieving item with id = ${id}`);
}

// Usage
// index.ts
// import {Model} from "./Model.ts";
const User = new Model("User");
const user = new User({"id": 5, "name": "Bob"});
user.save(); // "Saved document {"id": 5, "name": "Bob"} to User"
console.log(User.Model.myName); // "User"
// console.log(User.myName); // "User" // This option would be even better, but isn't supported in the existing code
User.get(5); // "Retrieving item with id = 5"
```

In the `Usage` section (very bottom of the code example above) I'm getting multiple errors in TypeScript. But running that code in a JavaScript file, works perfectly. So I know it's working and the code is accurate.

I think the biggest problem of what I'm trying to do is `return this.Document as any`. TypeScript is interpreting that as casting `this.Document` to a Model instance, when in reality it's not.

---

My question is this. In TypeScript how can I set it up where you can run `new MyClassInstance()` and have it return an instance of a different class? That has a bidirectional reference from `MyClassInstance` and the different class. In short, how do I get the following code working?

It's important that any solution works with the `Usage` section, and no modifications are made to that section. Except for the `User.Model.myName` vs `User.myName` section, which would be preferred as `User.myName`, but in the existing version functions as `User.Model.myName`.

---

For easy use, I also created a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&noImplicitThis=false&jsx=0#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-2ZHHcvkdkmar16uJ9JnpyXSLADknSJWqku6mysyWFv2zyWu6giMb+nvOKcpyMenUiABrRC7UieF-aIi+1AAAUth2Z0DmUU4iVISJIiIU5mAAUUwaAfE8TwP12cMEj7DcrwAbQwgBdWs7gIz9CKIVQ5HMKDjwASDotcn2aakr36K9mKcbA-VgbBkHJHM2J4UBMGQXZ7QWBZjQ2EC9gOf8-TOC4rhuQNQGDeBQ1eSMPhw74yz+AFgTBAAlP1RFcXFZE6WUAHc8F8WQYRiSlxBSFljwWLlQAAVRcX1vOo+g+UCoVdQkY0pRleVFWksgNXIWdfL3bAC0QWyxxKTw5T8wg5WPJLYBStKMtypNxDlFI5T0ABWKo5ULar5QAIRqOUmPIIq1WORBPDZUABTlSF3BhOFHjQCRKvMJq6vlRq9DlVrVHa8lIGSvLEoM-4iEBEEypvWlc0tfrBrKuVvLjQyduM-bzTzRATrAHKUrlAawAAFTuaoGGHLJQFsyBYE4GFQ1odx+NDVBOmwKpVFgVh-GQAByVgtwYYVOhhOQBMQbV-GHW19Msch9oAzwase+UzJxRBLMJhzEDshyfCc-oarlIA).

Comment: The returning type of a constructor must be the same as the class which the constructor belongs. Parsing as `any` is a workaround really bad, but compiler does not complain. On the other hand, don't declare classes in Typescript like you would do in Javascript...

Comment: @VRoxa Totally agree it’s bad practice to use any in this case. My question is how to fix it and how to do it better without breaking the API for users of the package.

Comment: So you want to create an object which is indeed a constructor function of an anonymous object? That's what I see

Comment: @VRoxa I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. This example is very similar to something like Mongoose if you've ever used that.

Comment: `return this.Document`
The error says "Property 'Document' is used before being assigned". That's because in your code snippet you never assign any value to `this.Document`!

Comment: @amakhrov My bad. Oversight on my part. In my project I'm working on it did have that. Just a mistake forgetting to copy that over when writing this question. Edited to fix that.

Comment: Are you looking to make the code behave differently (as implied by `User.myName`) or are you looking just to make the TypeScript typings reflect the existing code (as implied by the rest of your question)?  If it's the former, I'd strongly recommend changing your strategy entirely away from class constructors whose instances are themselves class constructors, since JS's prototypical inheritance plays poorly with that (you'll find that the "right" way to do it ends up confusing JS about `Object.getPrototypeOf(User)`. It *should* be `Model` but JS will make it `DocumentCarrier`).

Comment: Something like `const UserModel = new Model('User'); const user = new UserModel.ctor({})` will be much easier to implement.  Still, if you want to keep your code completely as-is and just help TS understand your typings, it can likely be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to interpret this question strictly as "how can I give typings to the existing code so that the compiler understands the code in the `Usage` section?"  That is, the answer should not touch the emitted JavaScript, but instead should only alter type definitions, annotations, and assertions.

Aside: the more general question "how should I implement a class whose instances are themselves class constructors" is one I won't attempt to address, since from my research the best answer here is "don't try to do that" since it plays poorly with the prototypical inheritance model in JS.  I'd instead lean strongly toward having a non-constructible class instance hold a property which is the constructor of the new class.  Something like [this Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AArENe1rF9BewAhEa9s4i0ekcIuHTIgD0Z83zg0bg8Xyr5HnEg3K836-4293uXyk8HlwlZiWNYdgDvgFRVOg9TQBem6gb2lCgRY2K4kuUEwb2DIKsyrLsmgnLcry+KHEuvZAA).  You'd be a lot happier in the long run, I expect.

Back to the typings: the main problem here is that TypeScript has no way to specify that a class constructor returns a type other than the class being defined.  This is either intentional (see [microsoft/TypeScript#11588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11588) or a missing feature (see [microsoft/TypeScript#27594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594)) but in any case it's not part of the language.

What we *can* do here is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).  When you write `class Model {}` you introduce both a class constructor object named `Model` and an interface type named `Model`.  That interface can be merged into, adding methods and properties that the compiler doesn't already know about.  In your case you could do this:

```
interface Model {
    new(object: {}): DocumentCarrier;
    Model: Model;
}
```

This lets the compiler know that `Model` instances, in addition to having the properties/methods declared in the class, also has a `Model` property whose type is `Model`, and, importantly, a constructor signature.  That's enough to get the following code to compile without error:

```
const User = new Model("User");
const user = new User({ "id": 5, "name": "Bob" });
user.save(); // "Saved document {"id": 5, "name": "Bob"} to User"
console.log(User.Model.myName); // "User"
User.get(5); // "Retrieving item with id = 5"
```

The compiler does think that `User.myName` exists, which it doesn't at runtime, but that's already a problem with the existing code so I'm not touching that here. It's possible to change the typings further so that the compiler knows that `User.Model.myName` exists and that `User.myName` does not exist, but that becomes quite complicated as it requires you to split `Model`'s interface into multiple types that you carefully assign to the right values.  So for now I'm ignoring it.

The only other change I'd make here would be to give different typings to the implementation of `Model`, like this:

```
class Model {
    myName: string;
    Document: Model;
    get!: (id: number) => void;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.myName = name;

        const self: Model = this;
        class Document extends DocumentCarrier {
            static Model: Model;

            constructor(object: {}) {
                super(self, object);
            }
        }
        Document.Model = self;

        (Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) as
            Array<keyof typeof DocumentCarrier>).forEach((key) => {
                Document[key] = this[key].bind(this);
            });

        this.Document = Document as Model;

        return this.Document;
    }
}
```

The only thing the compiler won't be able to verify in the above is that the `Document` class is a valid `Model`, so we use the assertion `Document as Model`.  Other than that I just put a few assertions (`get` is [definitely assigned](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions), and `Object.keys()` will return an array of keys of the `DocumentCarrier` constructor) so that you don't need to turn off the `--strict` compiler flag.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2wCuBbApgOwC4GEwCd8BLNfaAbwChobojtSMwQB5AIwCs1gsAuCgL4BuarRTwAJmhD8AspOkja0CGABuaAIT8AFFgAWRCPwTJ02PIRL4AlNAC8APmhr4RCSNE1g8DBCz4SDzw+DriUjLQ8hEANNDwnNx8gnZUysoGRgB09FiMzOxcPA7xiTxK6TSZEFnh0iV1IBU0ApStpqiYuATEpFkADvjwWMMAnv1oWaoaJQBmSBg8RL7QeobGcIidFj3WNvyu7hRe0D5+8CCTIPAA5joABgDK6mgS0BJb5ljQACTkAFKPFgAOSmAXoNyIs1Ga2yjRsAmgI1+5GqtQUIFqo2BYHQAnuNhEwkolFypFmYGAaCiGOOygwaAA7joEkVkuQBPtNmYupZevhmjSInIMUSSaBIDBovU0mJsbi0Px-MQMDdBR0viKIoKbmgsNpVu5+BhUGxSHYnC43B4ScozsqgiNQkx0ErwarUicMussTj0CUXWhPJVvL5-CppLMtfV7Ej1oK7eAoNztt80AAPPIYCQwDW83akOkh5T+MBYIjAIXSaNNW3F2j2gKOkIssrszlF+vpCBICahCCRuKspKEr0h1rFichvPYLLSkAlAcgWbBkM6QpJLIAazQowg67bWV1WAACkMRlhxmgWLNYRAbHZIGPKgBBQhgUYAHh3o3gsyRV5-imXx8tYjg2FkswhAAopS+g6DoP4Ws4spdsoM5YAA2j+AC6JTVNhu44VkbD0BId6jmh0CcqulRohhJQMZAVa1s+0D4HqSD4BgcbZBhgqtK084DOeYwTEeepzAsSwrDoRrQCaKBmrYBzWp2pxhhcVy3A8ABKeq9GoEJ0HkKDQIyRAGHQbyxn87j4qOrSUAA9M50AAKqqLqLluWRGZZFgEA+XQKD9CE3zkPOiKzEMZkAERZM5wmBXFIiNh5A5kLGDKMixOhxZ5pBxaO6VIJlAZMhlpA6OQ0Bxe4cX8AArHEcWBo1dUAEIJHF1GjmVfTTGgOiEtArl1c8GhvB8PLYBQ9USB1LV1e1-Bxd1bBxYiyKFfgcWUPaWlZNcdy7XOGK+gqo3jQVmX7eNh2XMdOlnSg8roNdbm3UVY1uQAKus8T9OWKyMvASAgG8ZrQGgGg8WaWB5PgcRsEg3xGBgADk3w9v0YX4Hkbz0HG1IZkY5aqhpUiUGdx46E1n11fp4Kw8ZlloGZFlWUcsZNXFQA)

Answer (score 0):

After roaming a bit, I got something.

Typescript complains about your solution because, even if you are returning a class `Document` internally in `Model` constructor, the compiler expects a `Model` instance, which is not constructable.

So, we need to make `Model` constructable. In fact, the same as making a function which returns instances of something.
First, let's declare your preovious `DocumentCarrier` class. Now, `DocumentCarrier` will have two properties, `model` and `name` (this was your previously keyed `myName` from `Model` class).

```
class DocumentCarrier {
    name: string = ``;
    constructor(public model: {}) { }
    save = () => console.log(`Saved document ${JSON.stringify(this.model)} to ${this.name}`)
}
```

After that, we need that function declaration that returns an instance model of type `DocumentCarrier`.

```
const Model = (name: string) => {
    return class extends DocumentCarrier {
        name: string = name;

        constructor(model: any) {
            super(model);
        }
    }
}
```

The function takes a `string` parameter and returns a constructor of type `DocumentCarrier` which takes an `any` object on its constructor and passes to the `DocumentCarrier` constructor.

We can call `Model` like this.

```
const User = Model('User');
const user = new User({id: 5, name: 'Bob'});
user.save(); // Saved document {"id":5,"name":"Bob"} to User
```

The call to `Model` is the only change made. Now `Model` call does not need a `new` keyword.
On the other hand, `name` in `DocumentCarrier` can be accessed from the last instance constructed.

---

In addition, this solution could be a bit more generic by defining generic types.

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

The type `Constructor` constraints a constructor function of any type `T`.

Now, we need to rewrite the `Model` function:

```
const Model = <T extends Constructor<{}>>(Type: T, name: string) => {
    return class extends Type {
        name: string = name;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
    }
}
```

`Model` now expects the same string as before but an additional parameter which is the type we want to instantiate, so

```
const User = Model(DocumentCarrier, 'User');
const user = new User({id: 5, name: 'Bob'});
user.save(); // Saved document {"id":5,"name":"Bob"} to User
```

Even more, since we are fulfilling a property `name` that belongs to the instance we are creating inside the `Model` function, we should constraint the input type to expect that `name` property.

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
interface DynamicallyConstructed {
    name: string;
}

class DocumentCarrier implements DynamicallyConstructed {
    name: string = ``;
    constructor(public model: {}) { }
    save = () => console.log(`Saved document ${JSON.stringify(this.model)} to ${this.name}`)
}

const Model = <T extends Constructor<DynamicallyConstructed>>(Type: T, name: string) => {
    return class extends Type {
        name: string = name;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
    }
}

const User = Model(DocumentCarrier, 'User');
const user = new User({id: 5, name: 'Bob'});
user.save();
```

Hope this helps a bit.
Please comment any issue.